# my javascript file will not link to my index.html file and i see nothing wrong with it. What is wrong with it?

Tags: javascript, html, linker

here is my index= https://github.com/25garcial/calculator/blob/main/index.html

here is my JavaScript= https://github.com/25garcial/calculator/blob/main/script.js

I don't know what is wrong with the code and i have asked my teacher and he does not know either.

Comment: Always check the browser console for errors before posting questions. You never defined a `g` variable, so an error is thrown and none of the JS runs. You also might consider looking for a new teacher if he/she was not able to spot this trivial (and easily debugged) problem.

Answer (score -1):

Replace script tag in your index file with this :

<​script​ ​src="​script.js​"​>​</​script​>

Answer (score -1):

At the bottom of the body tag in index.html file link your Javascript file with a script tag:

```
<script src="./yourfilename.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

To link your script try using:

```html
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

For more informations see : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp

Also note: You can use the `defer` attibute if you want your script to load after the HTML parsing and loading rather than putting it at the end of your body.

```html
<script src="script.js" defer></script>
```